# retrieving JSON data to another webpage using DETAILS button

Tags: javascript, html, json, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to retrieve remaining JSON data onto another webpage and dynamically populate the table on that webpage to display rest of JSON data by clicking on the Details button but whenever I click on the button I get an error that the URL doesn't exist in database.

My HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>CityScoot</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="scripts/get-routes.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    
        <header class="container bg-white">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-white static-top">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          <img src="images/logo.png" class="img-fluid" width=55 alt="" class="d-inline-block align-middle mr-2">
        </a>
    
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
    <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="routes.html">Tour Routes</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="guides.html">Tour Guides</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="scooters.html">Scooters</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="safety.html">Safety</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>
    </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
</header>



<main>
        <div class="container mt-5 p-0">
            <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid mt-5">
                <div class="container mt-2">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-9 pl-5">
                            <h1 class="display-4">CityScoot</h1>
                            <p> CityScoot tours are designed around areas of London, such as Soho, Bloomsbury, Greenwich, Camden Town etc. Routes take in major highlights, but also explore off-the-beaten-track. Each tour takes approximately four hours to complete. There are always short stops for drinks and a longer stop for lunch or dinner. Bookings can be made up to two-hours before the tour starts. </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3  d-none d-md-block float-right">
                            <img src="images/routes-icon.png" 
                            class="img-thumbnail rounded mx-auto "
                            alt="Routes Icon">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <section class="container bg-light">
    
    
            <table class="table table-bordered" id="datatable">
  <thead class="thead-light">
  <tr>
                          <th scope="col">Name</th>
                          <th scope="col">Day</th>
                          <th scope="col">Time</th>
                          <th scope="col">Highlights</th>
                          <th scope="col"><a href="route.html?routeID=0" class="btn btn-primary">Details</a></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="insertpoint">
                    
        </tbody>
</table>

</section>
            


<footer class="container-fluid text-center mt-5 mb-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
            <a href="">Accessibility</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
            <a href="">Privacy</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
            <a href="">Corporate Pages</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    </footer>
    </main>
    
     
    </body>
</html>
```

Part of JSON

```
{
   "routes":[
      {
         "routeID":"1",
         "name":"Camden Town",
         "startLat":"51.541837",
         "startLng":"-0.139199",
         "endLat":"51.550396",
         "endLng":"-0.140526",
         "day":"Sunday",
         "time":"9am",
         "highlights":"Camden Lock. Camden Market. Roundhouse. Camden High Street. Electric Ballroom.",
         "trailImage":"route-placeholder-image.png"
      },
      {
         "routeID":"2",
         "name":"Regents Park",
         "startLat":"51.523751",
         "startLng":"-0.154577",
         "endLat":"51.541565",
         "endLng":"-0.161842",
         "day":"Sunday",
         "time":"10am",
         "highlights":"Rose Garden. Boating Lakes. Mosque. Devonshire Terrace. Open Air Theatre. Camden Lock. Regents Canal. ",
         "trailImage":"route-placeholder-image.png"
      },
```

And JavaScript code

```
 window.onload = getRoutes;
    
    let xhr = false;
    
    function getRoutes() {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        if (xhr) {
            xhr.open("GET", "data/routes.json", true);
            xhr.send();
            xhr.onreadystatechange = displayRoutes;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("statusmessage").innerHTML = "error";
        }
    }
    function displayRoutes () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            if (xhr.status == 200) {
                const data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                let dataText = "";
const url = $(location).attr("search"); 
            const params = new URLSearchParams(url);
                for (let i in data.routes) {
                    if (data.routes[i].routeID >= parseInt(params.get("routeID"))) {
                        dataText += "<tr><td><strong>" +
                        data.routes[i].name + "</strong></td><td class='text-center'>" +
                        data.routes[i].day + "</td><td>" +
                        data.routes[i].time + "</td><td class='text-center'>" +
                        data.routes[i].highlights + "</td><td>" +
                        "<a href='route.html?routeId=" + data.routes[i].routeID + "' class='btn btn-sm btn-primary'>Details</a>" + 
                    "</td></tr>";
                    }
                }
            if (dataText.length < 1) {
                    document.getElementById("datatable").style.display = "none";
                        
            }
            document.getElementById("insertpoint").innerHTML = dataText;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("statusmessage").innerHTML = "Error. Could not perform the stated request Error: " + xhr.status;
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas of what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the url you are trying to get the data from? pretty sure you are missing a leading /

Comment: The button is on this URL and I'm trying to load data to route.html

Comment: But where are you trying to load it from?

Comment: Basically I'm trying to load the data from a JSON file, and the URL that I'm trying to load it to is route.html... it's a complete different URL to the one that I have included in this post

Comment: Where is this json file stored? What is the route?